# Authenticate over LDAP / Oracle table

Tags: oracle, authentication, frameworks, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need to authenticate over LDAP and have an Oracle table with usersnames and hashed passwords.

Is it possible to make LDAP use these table?

I just want to simulate a `fake` LDAP. When the client tries to log, the server just needs to hash the password and compare it with the one stored in the database table.

Just it. Is there a framework that implements all the LDAP protocol. I just want it to call my Java code.

Comment: It probably isn't worth trying to simulate an LDAP server if only because the protocol is non-trivial. Instead, just get a (simple) LDAP server and put the (hashed) passwords in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UnboundID LDAP SDK. The SDK provides a mechanism wherein an in-memory directory server can be created that acts like a real directory server (because it is). This is a better procedure than a mockup because the in-memory server is a full-fledged server without all the installation hassles. The fully compliant server allows LDAP clients to test n a real LDAP environment, which will result in more robust code.

#### see also

- [In-memory directory server](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/)